# Avoiding Memory Duplication when Storing DataFrame Views as Class Attributes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, class, memory-management, reference

I'm working with a large Pandas DataFrame and employing a [time series cross-validation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169207000000650) using a [rolling window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKVo4.png). During each iteration, I split the DataFrame into three separate datasets based on different date ranges. Due to memory constraints, I'd prefer that each of these three datasets be a view/reference of the original DataFrame rather than a memory-intensive copy.

I've come across various pandas functions(using `iloc` for example) that suppose to create a view of a DataFrame. My challenge arises when I try to store these views as attributes of a class or fields of named tuples. From my understanding, in certain situations, Python might end up storing a copy of the DataFrame as an attribute, which could exacerbate my memory issues.

1. What's the best practice to tackle this problem?
2. When assigning a  pandas DataFrame to a class attribute, how can I ensure Python uses
   a view and doesn't allocate memory for a new copy?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Python's behavior when storing objects as attributes, Python itself doesn't control whether a DataFrame is stored as a view or a copy. The behavior depends on Pandas' implementation and the operations you perform. Storing DataFrame slices obtained via .iloc as attributes should generally lead to memory-efficient views.